# Asp.NET Pass list of checked items to controller

Tags: html, asp.net, web, checkbox

I'm missing something here.  I have a table of items with checkboxes that I want to be able to select items from and then send that list of checked items to the controller.  I can't get anything passed to the controller.  I want a list or array that I can use in the controller.

Here is what I have:

```
@model Recipe2Grocery.ViewModels.GroceryListViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}
@section Scripts{
    <style type="text/css">
        table {
            color: white;
        }
</style>
}

<div style="margin: 20px;">
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "RecipeIngredient", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <table class="table">
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>
                Quantity
            </th>
            <th>
                IngredientName
            </th>
            <th>
                Category
            </th>
            @foreach (var item in Model.ShoppingList)
            {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.CheckBoxFor(modelItem => item.IsChecked)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Ingredient.Quantity)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Ingredient.IngredientName)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Ingredient.Category)
                </td>
            </tr>
            }
        </table>
        <input type="submit" />
}
```

Then I have a viewmodel as such:

```
public class ListItem
{
    public bool IsChecked { get; set; }
    public RecipeIngredient Ingredient { get; set; }

    public ListItem()
    {
        Ingredient = new RecipeIngredient();
    }
}

public class GroceryListViewModel
{
    public List<ListItem> ShoppingList { get; set; }

    public GroceryListViewModel()
    {
        ShoppingList = new List<ListItem>();
    }
}
```

Then my controller wants to be something like:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(GroceryListViewModel vm)
    {
        // blah
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
```

Comment: First of all your view can't work. What is the type of your model? If it's a list, then `@Html.DisplayNameFor(...)` won't work. Otherwise, you can't iterate over the model. What exactly is the issue? Does it throws an error?

Comment: sorry editing:  model is of type: @model IEnumerable<Recipe2Grocery.Models.RecipeIngredient>

Comment: and the error is nothing is passed to the controller.

Comment: You should add a `bool` property to your `RecipeIngredient` model and then render a `@Html.CheckboxFor(modelItem => item.CheckedProperty)`. It will output a properly configured set of checkboxes that will post to your controller (the post action should receive an `IEnumerable<RecipeIngredient>`).